# Why can't I change the title entry font of TOC using \cftsecfont?

Tags: xetex, titlesec, tocloft, adobe

[image]
Below is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[adobefonts]{ctex}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\title{Hello, \LaTeX !}
\author{kk@latex.com}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\tiny\heiti}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\tiny\heiti}

\tableofcontents

\section{\Huge\heiti Hello, Section!}
Google is a great company!

\subsection{\huge\heiti Hello, SubSection!}
tex.stackoverflow.com is a good site!

\end{document}
```

The result shows that `\cftsecfont` has no effects on the title entry font, even if I set the font size to **tiny**.

Why and how?

Comment: Well, you have `\Huge` there so you are saying `\tiny\Huge` which is just `\Huge`.

Comment: @cfr, Then, how to keep Huge in body and tiny in TOC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Never*** put manual formatting commands in the arguments to commands for things like `\title`, `\section` etc. Formatting should be separate from content. The name of the section is content. The size and font used to typeset section headings is format and should not be in the argument to `\section{}`. ***Form and content should be distinct.***

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% \usepackage[adobefonts]{ctex}
\let\heiti\sffamily
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Huge\heiti}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\huge\heiti}

\begin{document}

\title{Hello, \LaTeX !}
\author{kk@latex.com}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\tiny\heiti}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\tiny\heiti}

\tableofcontents

\section{Hello, Section!}
Google is a great company!

\subsection{Hello, SubSection!}
tex.stackoverflow.com is a good site!

\end{document}
```

[image: formatting distinct from contact]

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, and, especially for the TeX philosophy you provide.

Comment: @xmllmx I suppose it is philosophy. Certainly it is pragmatic philosophy: it works better when you do it this way!